# run SQL Commands from text box value

Tags: c#, mysql

i create small project that read data from sqlserver then insert into mysql table.
i want to users write SQL and mysql command into textbox.

**here is my problem**, when i run project the field that inserted into mysql table are: **myReader["STableName"].ToString()**

like this picture:

[image]

connections are fine, here is my code:

```
            string address;
            string username;
            string password;
            string database;
            address = textBox1.Text;
            username = textBox2.Text;
            password = textBox3.Text;
            database = textBox4.Text;


            //MySql
            string mysqladdress;
            string mysqlusername;
            string mysqlpassword;
            string mysqldatabase;
            mysqladdress = textBox7.Text;
            mysqlusername = textBox8.Text;
            mysqlpassword = textBox9.Text;
            mysqldatabase = textBox10.Text;

            //SQLCode 
            string sqlcmnd1;
            string sqlcmnd2;
            sqlcmnd1 = textBox5.Text;
            sqlcmnd2 = textBox6.Text;


            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString =
            "Data Source=" + address + ";" +
            "Initial Catalog=" + database + ";" +
            "User id=" + username + ";" +
            "Password=" + password + ";";
            try
            {
                conn.Open();       
                SqlDataReader myReader = null;
                SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlcmnd1, conn);
                myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();    
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    string connectionString = @"server=" + mysqladdress + ";" + "username=" + mysqlusername + ";" + "password=" + mysqlpassword + ";" + "database=" + mysqldatabase + "";
                    MySqlConnection connection = null;
                    MySqlDataReader reader = null;
                    try
                    {
                        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
                        connection.Open();
                        string stm = sqlcmnd2;//here is my problem
                        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(stm, connection);
                        DataTable table = new DataTable();
                        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                    }
```

**sqlcmnd2:**

```
INSERT INTO test (CusCode,STableName,Date,ModdatZaman) VALUES ('" + myReader["CusCode"].ToString() + "','" + myReader["STableName"].ToString() + "','" + myReader["Date"].ToString() + "','" + myReader["ModdatZaman"].ToString() + "')
```

**sqlcmnd1:**

```
SELECT * FROM __TempUserCompRep__
```

Comment: If you don't show with what you fill the variable _sqlcmnd2_ is it impossible to understand what's happening here. Probably it is a case of bad string concatenation instead of using parameters.

Comment: @Steve thank you, i'd edited article. please check it again.

Comment: And you type that string into the textbox hoping that the "myReader" literal text becomes a reference to the _myReader_ variable ? This will not happen

Comment: @Steve it work without putting sql command into textbox, how i can do that with text box?

Comment: In the textbox write _INSERT INTO test (CusCode,STableName,Date,ModdatZaman) VALUES (@cidcode,@table,@date)_ the in your code create three parameters with the above names and the set their values from the myReader variable. However keep in mind that this approach is a recipe for disasters. Your user can type anything. Even DROP database <databasename> and you will have no more a database to work with

Comment: @Steve can you please add an answer and Better explaining with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text from a textbox is considered as a full string it not replace the actual value of the variable .

You need to use prepared statement for that.

In textbox6 you write the command like this :

```
INSERT INTO test (CusCode,STableName,Date,ModdatZaman) VALUES (@CusCode,@STableName,@Date,@ModdatZaman)
```

After that in code, bind the parameter with variable from you actually want to take value.

For example:

```
      MySqlConnection con = null;
        try
        {
            string myConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=test;uid=root;pwd=root;";

                con = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);

                string CmdString = textBox6.Text.ToString();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(CmdString, con);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@CusCode", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@STableName", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@ModdatZaman", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
                 cmd.Parameters["@CusCode"].Value = myReader["CusCode"].ToString();
                 cmd.Parameters["@STableName"].Value = myReader["STableName"].ToString();
                 cmd.Parameters["@Date"].Value = myReader["Date"].ToString();
                 cmd.Parameters["@ModdatZaman"].Value = myReader["ModdatZaman"].ToString();

                con.Open();
                int RowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (RowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Insert Query sucessfully!");
                }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

*Note: I consider all four columns are varchar type in the database. you modify it according to your requirement*

Answer (score 0):

Hello Muhammad i would suggest you not to execute the sql commands from text box as there is a high chance of sql injection attacks , try to avoid as much you can , its a suggestion for more secured application

Comment: thank you sir, 
i use this form only from local databases